# Google Timezone

Tags: javascript, api

I'm a little puzzled using the Google timezone, while this works fine I cannot get the correct time.

This is my code:

```js
var xhr;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
  xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

var timeStamp = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000);

var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=41.010734,9.0039&timestamp=" + timeStamp ;

xhr.open("GET", url, false);
xhr.send(null);
var resp = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

var time = new Date((resp.dstOffset + resp.rawOffset + timeStamp) * 1000);

var span = " AM";
var hours = time.getUTCHours();
if (hours > 12) {
  span = " PM";
  hours -= 12;
}
CurrentTime = ((hours + '').length == 1 ? '0' + hours : hours) + ":" + ((time.getUTCMinutes() + '').length == 1 ? '0' + time.getUTCMinutes() : time.getUTCMinutes()) + span;
console.log("Time is: " + CurrentTime);
```

I am using and returning the data, however the because I am passing the time from the UK and retrieving for a location in France the hours are off by 1 hour. I know this has to do with DST and Raw values from the returned data but cannot work out how to ensure this is always correct.
Please help me.

Comment: The timestamp passed in to the Google api and to which you are adding needs to be utc, not local, I think, since offset is relative to utc. But that is what you seem to be getting. Puzzling.

Comment: Based on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro it looks like you do not need quotes around the latitude or longitude. I cannot imagine that is the issue.

Comment: No, that's not the issue the return time is out by 1 hour

Comment: If you change the quotes, does the behavior change?

Comment: Also if you change the coordinates to be for Chiago or Calgary, say, is it still off an hour or is it more? That would test your hunch of its being a dst issue or something else.

Answer (score 0):

To get a utc time stamp, you can use:

```
var now = new Date;
var utc_timestamp = Date.UTC(
    now.getUTCFullYear(),
    now.getUTCMonth(), 
    now.getUTCDate() ,          
    now.getUTCHours(), 
    now.getUTCMinutes(), 
    now.getUTCSeconds(), 
    now.getUTCMilliseconds()
);
```

Updated fiddle:

```js
var xhr;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
  xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

var now = new Date;
var utc_timestamp = Date.UTC(
    now.getUTCFullYear(),
    now.getUTCMonth(), 
    now.getUTCDate() ,          
    now.getUTCHours(), 
    now.getUTCMinutes(), 
    now.getUTCSeconds(), 
    now.getUTCMilliseconds()
);

var timeStamp = Math.floor(utc_timestamp / 1000);

var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=41.010734,9.0039&timestamp=" + timeStamp ;

xhr.open("GET", url, false);
xhr.send(null);
var resp = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

var time = new Date((resp.dstOffset + resp.rawOffset + timeStamp) * 1000);

var span = " AM";
var hours = time.getUTCHours();
if (hours > 12) {
  span = " PM";
  hours -= 12;
}
CurrentTime = ((hours + '').length == 1 ? '0' + hours : hours) + ":" + ((time.getUTCMinutes() + '').length == 1 ? '0' + time.getUTCMinutes() : time.getUTCMinutes()) + span;
console.log("Time is: " + CurrentTime);
```